# How to add app.config to Visual Studio 2012 Web Express lib project?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio

How can I add a configuration file to Visual Studio 2012 Web Express library project?

I tried following the [msdn instructions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms184658.aspx) but I just don't have the `Application Configuration File` template. I tried looking all over in the properties of the project to specify the config file, but it's nowhere to be found.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Libraries* don't generally have configuration files. When an application loads, the configuration it loads will be the one associated with that *application* - not the libraries within it.

You *can* create app config files for libraries, and load them explicitly - but it's a bit of a pain. Consider exposing configuration directly in your API, and allowing the application *consuming* the library to provide the configuration appropriately.

Comment: How about console application? I can change the type of my project to that instead. Regardless, I don't have that menu entry.

Comment: @drozzy: I suspect it's not present in Web Express as that's designed for web applications, which use different config files. If you want to write non-web apps, you should use a different flavour of Express. (Unfortunately the "client apps" version of Express for VS2012 isn't out yet, unless you're using Windows 8... but you could use VS2010.) You could probably edit the project file manually after creating the file...

Comment: It is available for Console Apps. Simply name the config file `app.config` and express whatever will pick it up. In my case I was hosting a WCF service from a console app, and when I wrote an app.config file, WCF service read all it's values from there automagically!

Comment: @JonSkeet Can you help me in similar question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26624516/from-where-to-read-keys-in-class-library-webapi

Comment: @little: Well can't you follow the exact advice I gave in this answer? That's basically all I'd say on your question...

Comment: @JonSkeet, sometimes there are good reasons why someone might want to write a non-web app using Web Express. In my case I write both web apps and console apps, often using the same projects and sometimes within the same solution. I don't want to fire up a different editor to work on a different part of a project.

Comment: @LouiseEggleton: IIRC, you can install Web Express and the Desktop version on the same machine, and it basically unlocks the relevant project types.

Comment: @JonSkeet Wouldn't I still have to switch between Express and Desktop for each project type or are you saying that if both are installed all project types are available from both Express and Desktop?

Comment: @LouiseEggleton: The latter - I think. It's a long time since I've done that though.

Answer (score 2):

In ASP.NET, it's called a "Web application file", and the filed is named as "web.config".