# from where to read keys in Class library/webapi

Tags: c#, asp.net, app-config, asp.net-web-api

i have a webapi project that uses cache library.I am using **cache duration** key that is used inside cache library.My question is what is the standard practice where should i put Cache duration key,from Where to pick the value of cache duration, inside appconfig of cache library or from web.config of webapi?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The web.config is the place to go in a web application. There's no such thing as app.config in an ASP.NET application. You could always build some mechanism to load configuration data from custom places but the first place a developer would look for such things is the web.config.

Comment: Cache library is separate class library.I think i can add app.config in that Cache library.now my question is where to add cache duration key inside webapi application or inside cache layer?

Comment: My point is that even if you add an `app.config` to your class library this file will not be used by your web application.

Comment: So i should consider adding the key in web.config and access it in Cache libraray like var CacheDuration = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["CacheDuration"];Is it so?

Comment: Well, if you don't want to force the consumers of your class library to have a configuration file, it would be much better to have your class library simply take an integer (or TimeStamp) parameter for this duration. Don't attempt to read it from a config. What if I want to use your Cache library but I don't wanna use config files, for example I have my config in a database. By using this `System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["CacheDuration"];` you are imposing me where to store my settings. Basically what I am trying to say is that you should invert the control.